# all jar files using my log4j. too much information on log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I started learning log4j. It is awesome. But my project is tooo big. has so many jar files. when I set my log level to DEBUG, all other jar files debug messages are printing in my log file. With in a minute the logfile size increased to 5MB.

I want to just display my log messages in my class. How I can do that ?

My configuration is as follows

**log4j.properties**

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = ./logs
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/logs.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=[%d] %5p -%c.%M - %m%n
```

**MyClass.java**

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
logger.debug("Hello World");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set individual packages to different logging levels

e.g.

```
log4j.logger.com.mystuff=DEBUG, FILE
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=INFO, FILE
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=ERROR, FILE
```