# Stop log4j debug printing from third party Jars

Tags: java, debugging, jar, log4j

I'm using classes from other Jars which use classes from other Jars that use log4j. I cannot change any of these Jars.

A lot of these classes are printing debug to the console at startup when debugging in IntelliJ.

I'm looking for ways to stop this as it's irritating.

I've tried creating a log4j.properties file with "error" log level and had it load in the main() of my application as well as setting the default logger to "error" level. I also checked and all the Jars have a properties inside but non are specfying what log level (they just say what version the Jar is). I've tried creating my own properties files for the classes to use which works but they've already printed their debug before they load the file.

Here's some of the debug chatter being produced:

```
12:54:17.660 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration - FileName set to xxx.properties
12:54:17.665 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is null, name is xxx.properties
12:54:17.665 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file xxx.properties at null: no protocol: xxx.properties
12:54:17.668 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the path xxx.properties
12:54:17.668 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration - Base path set to file:///C:/myProgram/xxx.properties
12:54:17.680 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration - FileName set to yyy.properties
12:54:17.680 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is null, name is yyy.properties
12:54:17.681 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file yyy.properties at null: no protocol: yyy.properties
12:54:17.681 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the path yyy.properties
12:54:17.681 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration - Base path set to file:///C:/myProgram/yyy.properties
```

Here are my .properties files:

---log4j.properties---

```
log4j.rootLogger=error
```

---xxx.properties---

```
log4j.rootLogger=error
```

---yyy.properties---

```
log4j.rootLogger=error
```

my main method starts like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

The log4j.properties file is being loaded fine with no issue, and is happy with "log4j.rootLogger=error". (if I add ', R' or ', stdout' like I've seen in [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760493/error-could-not-find-value-for-key-log4j-appender-error-during-deploying-on-tomc) it complains but I suspect that is due to me being on Windows ).

If this isn't possible, let me know and I'll just accept it, live with it and stop looking.

This project is run by a large audience using windows, mac and linux. (the project is a test harness for developers who need to run the collection of Jars do develop new ones for the collection)

--- edit ----

I've investigated the suggestion of putting a log4j.xml in my project's src/main/resource folder but can't get it to work.

Everything I read indicates the log4j.xml should work but I'm running out of things to try. As a last ditch attempt I tried to google:
 "org.apache.commons.configuration" debug stop 
and google sent me to my own question haha

Here's my log4j.xml which doesn't seem to be stopping the org.apache.commons.configuration from each jar debug printing every time those classes are initilised (which happens a few hundred times a second).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>

    <appender name="CA" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache.commons.configuration">
        <level value="error"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="off"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CA"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I've rebuilt my project and repackaged my jar. I'm hoping I don't have to put the log4j.xml into each Jar's resources folder? :/

Is there a way to see if it's loading the log4j.xml file?

Is there something I need to do to make all the Jars which are presumably instantiting their own instances of log4j use this log4j.xml?

I tried this now for my main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

but I am still seeing the console spammed with DEBUG messages from org.apache.commons.configuration

-- edit 2 --

Still stuck. I tried simplying to a really basic example and DEBUG output is still appearing in the console.

Here is my simple main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {
  PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
  Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR);
  PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("log4j.xml");
}
```

Here are the imports:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
```

3rd line causes this output to appear:

```
10:04:08.526 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration - FileName set to log4j.xml
10:04:08.536 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is null, name is log4j.xml
10:04:08.536 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file log4j.xml at null: no protocol: log4j.xml
10:04:08.546 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the path log4j.xml
```

Here is the log4j.xml which I confirmed is being loaded by renaming it and seeing a load file error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>

    <root>
        <level value="error"/>
        <priority value="off"/> 
    </root>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="error"/>
        <priority value="off"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.commons.configuration">
        <level value="error"/>
        <priority value="off"/>
    </logger>


    <logger name="org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration">
        <level value="error"/>
        <priority value="off"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.commons">
        <level value="error"/>
        <priority value="off"/>
    </logger>


    <logger name="org.apache">
        <level value="error"/>
        <priority value="off"/>
    </logger>


</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: try this solution if you don't want to print 3rd party jar file "debug". https://stackoverflow.com/a/20530943/8035260

Comment: thanks! nice find, will try it now. Didn't know log4j had XML files with had higher precedence to the .properties files!

Comment: I've put the log4j.xml in every possible folder (working directory, target folder, root, src/ src/main/ src/main/resources/ and anywhere else I can think) but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I can't tell if it's being loaded (not really sure how I would test for that). I presume it's automagically loaded if it is found as the other question you linked doesn't say that there needs to be any code added to specify the file, you just make the log4j.xml and put it in the src/main/resources folder and it works. I'll keep googling and see if I can find out how to check if it is being loaded.

Comment: HI @jon. Are you trying to print in log file or console?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052920/all-jar-files-using-my-log4j-too-much-information-on-log-file?rq=1

Comment: it's the console which I'm trying to stop  org.apache.commons.configuration from spamming. I followed that log4j.xml lead and think I've found a working solution now. I'll give one more comment when I've nailed it down but I'll accept this answer as it was a great help. log4j.xml is the way to go.

Comment: updated the question with latest info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file called "logback-test.xml" and tried placing it in every possible folder I could think of, finally found if I put it into here "Log4JTest\out\production\Log4JTest" (where Log4JTest is the name of my test IntelliJ project) then it is found.

The loopback-test.xml has the following contents:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
        <logger name="org.apache" level="OFF"/>
    </configuration>
```

and it seems to have done the job!

Here's my Main.java

```
package com.company;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigurationException {
        PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("log4j.xml");
    }
}
```

and here's the output console:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50725', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50725', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now to test on the full project... will mark this as 'solved' if it solves the original problem.

Comment: Yep, tried on my original big project and it worked. Had to put the file in "<projectname>/target/classes" (as it's a maven project)